# DB2 - optimized query - apply function to current date or db column?

Tags: sql, date, timestamp, db2

I need to write a query that will be as efficient as possible returning rows that have **mycol** (*timestamp* value) equal to today's date minus 100 or 200 days. (exactly 100 or 200 days ago - not a range)

Note that **mycol** always has **00.00.000000** time. (Ignore why that is)

Here is one example of how this can be written:

```
select * from mytable mt where 
date(mycol) in (current date - 100 days, current date - 200 days)
```

I'm thinking this may be more efficient:

```
select * from mytable mt where
mycol in (timestampadd(16,-100,timestamp(current date,'00:00:00')),
          timestampadd(16,-200,timestamp(current date,'00:00:00')))
```

The reason I believe it is more efficient is because I'm not calling a function on `mycol` (as I did in the first example) and the calculations on `current date` happen only once per execution of this query and not for every row.

Am I correct in my assumption?

Comment: Are you looking for comparation  with two values or for a range between dates?

Comment: Just two values - not a range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write the second version as:

```
select *
from mytable mt
where mycol in (timestamp(current date - 100 days, '00:00:00'),
                timestamp(current date - 200 days, '00:00:00')
               );
```

If you care about performance, then you should have an index on `mytable(mycol)`, because this will speed the query.  Without an index, the additional overhead is the call to `date()` in each row.  You would need to run timings in your environment to determine whether that is an issue in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think second option is more eficient but for other reason.

If you declare an index over your column `mycol` the IN operator will be much faster.

But at the moment you perform `date(mycol)` db can't use the index anymore.

The best way is test both query unsing `analyze`/ `explain`.

**ADD INFO:**

You should consider using `EXISTS` instead of `IN` as show **[HERE](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/ibmdb2/w/wiki/6745.exists-versus-in)**

Test your two querys using [EXPLAIN de DB2](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro/src/tpc/db2z_toolsimprovequeryperformance.dita) or DB2 SQL Performance Analyzer
And then try the same using the `EXISTS` version.

Comment: What if there is no index on `mycol`? Is there any difference?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do explains/analyze as I don't have access to this DB. Just providing the query to someone who does but doesn't have the application knowledge.

Comment: Sorry in that case Im not sure, the best way is your try using `EXPLAIN` as i justt add to my answer. And compare what the planer is doing.

Comment: EXISTS is a replace for IN (subquery)...that is not the case here.